# AWS Serverless Image Handler Error Handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using the latest version of the AWS Serverless Image Handler Stack Formation, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/considerations.html) AWS Lambda has a limit of 6MB for request and response payload. My images are already stored on an S3 bucket, I would like to modify the Image Handler in such a way that if any error occurs during the transformation process, the URL for the object stored on the original S3 bucket be returned, i.e. the object URL for the original unedited object. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Before this can be answered you will likely need to add a code example of what you have in place right now as well as what you've already tried and any errors you cannot resolve. I've flagged this for more information.

Comment: I am using the default configuration of the [AWS Serverless Image Handler stack](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler)

Answer (score 0):

So as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/considerations.html#default-fallback-image) there are three vars to the template

> EnableDefaultFallbackImage, FallbackImageS3Bucket, and FallbackImageS3Key. Before enabling this feature, if you use an Amazon S3 bucket policy in the fallback image Amazon S3 bucket, you must edit the bucket policy to allow CustomResourceFunction and ImageHandlerFunction AWS Lambda function to get the default fallback image object.

In the corresponding [code](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/blob/6345555cab0843ac7d1125b6828ea2cca49771b6/source/custom-resource/index.js#L409) you can use the original source bucket where the objects are getting uploaded and with the key which you are trying to modify.

specifically this part of the code

```
        try {
        data = await s3.headObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).promise();
        break;
    } catch (error) {
        if (retry === retryCount || !['AccessDenied', 'Forbidden'].includes(error.code)) {
            console.error(`Either the object does not exist or you don't have permission to access the object: ${bucket}/${key}`);
            throw {
                code: 'FallbackImageError',
                message: `Either the object does not exist or you don't have permission to access the object: ${bucket}/${key}`
            };
        } else {
            console.log('Waiting for retry...');
            await sleep(retry);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail in case the source image is bigger than 6MB, giving the same exception again?

Comment: you dont have to return the object itself , you can return a [one time url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html). My point for sharing above information that this is achievable without too much work. As [lambda request response size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) doesnt allow bigger objects.

Answer (score 0):

2 things I would do:

1. add image compression to mitigate this inside the nested `resize` object `compressionLevel: 9` (9 is the max and we are currently seeing images go down from 20mb to 3mb or so)
2. pass a signed url to the client in conjunction and have the error handler and render that in its place on error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in your webpage then simply changing the output image format to webp can solve the issue.

Add this filter to the url.

`filters:format(webp)`

Example:

https:/cloudfront-endpoint/filters:format(webp)/your-large-image.jpg